# Redirect / to /index.jsp when deployed to root

Tags: jetty

I am struggling with a webapp deployment in Jetty 6. Previously the the webapp was deployed in `/mywebapp` and everytime I accessed `http://localhost/mywebapp/` Jetty directed me to `http://localhost/mywebapp/index.jsp`.

When I change the `contextPath` to `/`, suddenly the redirect behaviour is broken. Instead, Jetty makes an internal forward request.

**Does anyone have any input why this is happening?** The `DefaultServlet` has the following settings:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>welcomeServlets</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>redirectWelcome</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was not exactly the change of `contextPath` that made the redirects fail. Instead, I realized that simply the action of adding `mywebapp.xml` into `$JETTY_HOME/contexts/` made Jetty not execute the redirects.

I overcame this issue by deleting my context XML file, instead renaming `$JETTY_HOME/webapps/mywebapp.war` to `$JETTY_HOME/webapps/root.war` solved the issue.

Unclear why this happened in the first place, but I'm happy things are back on track.

Comment: It seems that adding a new context automatically doesn't use webdefault.xml. Adding <Set name="defaultsDescriptor">/home/smith/dev/webdefault.xml</Set> could possibly remedy this.